# Поиск целых и вещественных чисел

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста с регулярными выражениями. Пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение, чтобы можно было выбирать целые или дробные числа от 0 до 99, содержащие не более 2 символов после точки.

```
import re

result = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}\.{1}\d{1,2}\b|\b\d{1,2}\.{0}\b', '10 rew 14.03 ytr 123 dsffd 15.443 er')
print(result)
```

Данный код выводит ответ

```
['10', '14.03', '15']
```

а надо

```
['10', '14.03']
```

Не могу понять, как сделать это правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```py
import re
pattern = r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?!\.?\d)'
print(re.findall(pattern, '10 rew 14.03 ytr 123 dsffd 15.443 er', re.ASCII))
# => ['10', '14.03']
```

См. [пример работы программы на Python](https://ideone.com/iZyias). Выражение находит

- `(?<!\d)` - место в строке, сразу перед которым нет цифры
- `(?<!\d\.)` - место в строке, сразу перед которым нет последовательности "цифра + точка"
- `\d{1,2}` - одна или две цифры
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - необязательная последовательность "точка + одна или две цифры"
- `(?!\.?\d)` - сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть точки и цифры или просто цифры.

Благодаря флагу `re.ASCII` шаблон `\d` находит цифры из набора `0-9`.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/yOguGH/1).

Ещё один вариант выражения с границами слова:

```
\b(?<!\d\.)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b(?!\.\d)
```

См. [пример работы этого регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/yOguGH/3).